# how to set datalist selected value in a field using javascript.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<datalist id="SelectEntityPrimaryNames"> //datalist contains list of country
    <option id="1" value="india"></option>
    <option id="2" value="US"></option>
    <option id="3" value="Canada"></option>
</datalist>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="SelectEntityPrimaryName" style="width: 75%;" placeholder="Title"list="SelectEntityPrimaryNames" />

$("#SelectEntityPrimaryName").val()
```

how can I get the value which is already selected in datalist through jquery

Comment: @SanKrish but why he is giving id of `input` why not `datalist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if

```
$("#SelectEntityPrimaryName option:selected").val()
```

will work or not.If not you should try

```
$("#SelectEntityPrimaryName option:selected").attr('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

please use below code for getting current selected option into datalist by jquery technique.

```html
$("#SelectEntityPrimaryName option:selected").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
<select id="SelectEntityPrimaryNames">
    <option id="1">india</option>
    <option id="2">US</option>
    <option id="3"></option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="SelectEntityPrimaryName" style="width: 75%;" placeholder="Title" />

$("#SelectEntityPrimaryName").val($("#SelectEntityPrimaryNames").val());
```

Comment: i want  only text and this is returning me whole object which does not contain text.